# Get previous webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am at a loss as to how this is best handled in asp.net

I have a webpage with a lot of panels, and tables that is populated with data from mysql request. Now this data might change depending on an input. All the data are buttons that will open a modal windows displaying data.

My issue is that when I press the button the modal opens, but all the tables are reset to the standard "sql data" and the panels collapses. I basiclly want to be able to post back to the exact spot the user was earlier, including where on the page he had scrolled.

I get that the created html istanse is destroyed as soon as the person moved to the modal but how can i store the current exact state of the webpage so when the user goes back he is met with the exact "copy" he left. I've looked into viewstate and state management, and also to check for postback but still havent been able to solve it.

Is there any good tutorial covering this topic?
I've looked into this: [Persisiting the state of a webpage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7655/Persisting-the-state-of-a-web-page)

But thats based on ASP2.0 (im at 4.5) and dated 2006. Would this approach still be my best option or is this fixed in a better way on newer ASP.NET version?

Comment: You can consider making Ajax calls, then the user never leaves the page.

Comment: Will look into it and mark as solved if it solves my issue :) Thanks.